# Series featuring telepaths, raising children with aliens to learn each other's language

Tags: story-identification, aliens, languages, extrasensory-perception

So, I'm trying to remember the name of a series of books that features telepaths who contact people with their minds across the galaxy, and send ships. I remember one of the key ones was on a moon in the outer solar system, I want to say Io.

There was different ratings of telepaths, L1s were the most powerful, and extremely rare. 2 L2's that were perfectly matched, or maybe 3 L3's, could almost do what an L1 could do. But much lower than that, and they had relatively little power, although they were still matched.

There were multiple books, novel sized.

Also, the books featured a species of aliens who I believe were at war at first, but later they were at peace with humans. In order to help learn about each other, they started small communities where both human and aliens were raised together, so they could better understand each other's language.

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds suspiciously familiar. I reckon J. Michael Straczynski has read them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Anne Mcaffrey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_McCaffrey)'s [Pegasus](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_22?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=anne%20mccaffrey%20pegasus&x=0&y=0&sprefix=anne%20mccaffrey%20pegasus) [series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?701)?

It progresses over time.  Starts entirely on earth, eventually they get to telepaths on a moon launching interstellar craft.  Fight a war, etc.  Many books in the series, a fair bit of fun to read.

Comment: That's it. The series I was thinking of was the Tower and the Hive, I didn't know there was a series before that. Thanks!

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto She has a ton of great books.  DragonRiders of Pern is best known, but there are a whole bunch more!  Glad to help out.

Comment: The Tower and the Hive is part of the Rowan series, not Pegasus.  The Rowan includes "The Rowan", "Damia", "Damia's Children", and others.

Comment: @Toby Isn't Pegasus the precursor to the Rowan series?  I.e. The whole telepath thing starts with the Pegasus series, then later in time, in universe, they have the telepaths doing interstellar transport.  Or am I recalling this wrong?

Comment: You're probably right.  I don't think I ever read any of the Pegasus books.  (I believe the series name is actually "Talents".)  When I first read the original question, it reminded me distinctly of "Damia" & "Damia's Children".

Comment: Pegasus is definitely the precursor of the Rowan series, and the more all-purpose name for the series is [*The Talents Universe*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?700). For example, *Pegasus in Flight* introduces Peter Reidinger, while *The Rowan* has FT&T being run by a direct descendant named Peter Reidinger IV.